# Why Else code not fire when select another file extension?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I want to upload only PDF files and I tried the following controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
    String FileExt = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName).ToUpper();

    if (FileExt == ".PDF")
    {
        Stream str = files.InputStream;
        BinaryReader Br = new BinaryReader(str);
        Byte[] FileDet = Br.ReadBytes((Int32)str.Length);

        FileDetailsModel Fd = new Models.FileDetailsModel();
        Fd.FileName = files.FileName;
        Fd.FileContent = FileDet;

        SaveFileDetails(Fd);

        return RedirectToAction("FileUpload");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.FileStatus = "Invalid file format.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

But if I select any file, it is accepted, and the message "Invalid file format." does not appear.

This is the view markup:

```
@model AljawdahNewSite.Models.PDFModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.files, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, "", new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.files, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-success">
                @ViewBag.FileStatus
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.Action("FileDetails", "FileUpload")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

when I select PDF file and click upload button it save the file but when select any file other than PDF and click upload it show the following error :

```
A public action method 'FileDetails' was not found on controller 'AljawdahNewSite.Controllers.FileUploadController'.
```

What do I need to change in the code to view the message when select any file other than .PDF ?

Comment: Have you debugged through your code to see what's happening? Are you sure it's not executing the `else` code fine, and it's a problem with the view?

Comment: @JonSkeet I made a debug when I select pdf file the system working and save the file but when I select file not pdf and click uplod button it show the error A public action method 'FileDetails' was not found on controller 'AljawdahNewSite.Controllers.FileUploadController'.

Comment: @JonSkeet when I debug it goes inside the ELSE but not show the message

Comment: Use try..catch block. Move your code inside try ..catch block. This will help you to catch exception and you can add your message before it throws exception.

Comment: @ZiadAdnan: **1)** Update your code to show what exactly name of your controller where the `public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase files)` action method is declared. **2)** What is the view name that code is shown above. **3)** Show declaration of the action method `FileDetails` in the  `AljawdahNewSite.Controllers.FileUploadController` controller. This will avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The error you included to the question having a single meaning:  when the `@Html.Action()` helper trying to render required markup the `FileDetails` action method was not found in your `FileUploadController` controller.

> A public action method `FileDetails` was not found on controller
> `AljawdahNewSite.Controllers.FileUploadController`.

Therefore, you should check that your `AljawdahNewSite.Controllers.FileUploadControll` controller contains the `FileDetails` action method.

Another possible reason if you prefixed the `FileDetails` method with `[HttpPost]` attribute, but the `@Html.Action()` requires `[HttpGet]`.